# Can not show my text in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I do not know why I cannot print my "pocetDatabaze3 in my UILabel.

This is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var aktualniPocet: UILabel!
var pocetDatabaze2 = 0
var pocetDatabaze3 = "dfh"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let url = NSURL(string: "http://servis.dronysitmp.cz/cteni_baterie.php") {
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            //print(data)

            if let pocetDatabaze = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue){

                self.pocetDatabaze2 = Int(pocetDatabaze as String)!
                //self.pocetDatabaze3 = String(describing: pocetDatabaze)
            }

        }

        );
        task.resume()
    }

    pocetDatabaze3 = String(pocetDatabaze2 as Int)
    aktualniPocet.text = pocetDatabaze3

}
```

In UILabel it shows me "0" but it should be "25." After loading this View I have two more actions. And when I use them, it shows the correct value. The rest is:

```
@IBAction func odecteni(_ sender: UIButton) {
    pocetDatabaze2 = pocetDatabaze2 - 1
    self.pocetDatabaze3 = String(pocetDatabaze2 as Int)
    aktualniPocet.text = pocetDatabaze3
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a thread issue. `URLSession` is is asynchronous, so you have to update the UI in the `completionHandler`.

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    //print(data)

    if let pocetDatabaze = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue) {

        self.pocetDatabaze2 = Int(pocetDatabaze as String)!
        self.pocetDatabaze3 = String(pocetDatabaze2 as Int)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.aktualniPocet.text = pocetDatabaze3
        }
    }

})
```

You need a call to `DispatchQueue.main` because you should update the UI in the main thread. Then you can comment out the other two calls.

Comment: thank you very much. I have to edited the code more:

self.pocetDatabaze3 = String(self.pocetDatabaze2 as Int)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.aktualniPocet.text = self.pocetDatabaze3
                    }

Just inserted "self"...again, thank you

Comment: @JosefNavratil And then why have you accepted the other answer? It doesn't update the UI and is wrong.

Comment: @paper1111 It would work exactly the same if not used in Main Thread as it's not a major task, switching between the queues is not required in this case. Still I would add it in my answer, so Josef can get a bit idea about it.

Comment: @MaulikBhuptani from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/main_thread_checker "Updating UI on a thread other than the main thread is a common mistake that can result in missed UI updates, visual defects, data corruptions, and crashes."

Comment: My friend @paper1111 you haven't understood my point. Anyways I believe Josef has his answer which he accepted as correct and also matters the most.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
 if let url = NSURL(string: "http://servis.dronysitmp.cz/cteni_baterie.php") {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let pocetDatabaze = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue){
                 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       self.aktualniPocet.text = pocetDatabaze as! String
                   }
              }
         }
    );
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You should only update UI From the Main Thread.

```
    if let url = NSURL(string: "http://servis.dronysitmp.cz/cteni_baterie.php") {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        //This block executes on a background thread

        if let pocetDatabaze = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue){

            DispatchQueue.main.async{ // Add this to your code
              // This block executes on the Main Thread and the UI updates properly
              self.pocetDatabaze2 = Int(pocetDatabaze as String)!
            }
        }

    }
    );
    task.resume()
}
```

For more information about Multithreading and GCD in Swift you can read these articles:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch

https://www.raywenderlich.com/148513/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-1

Comment: pocetDatabaze is not UIElement, it's an integer. So I think it should not require Main thread to update its own value.

Comment: setting the text part is missing here